# MySQLi SELECT rows from TableA where 0 rows in TableB

Tags: php, select, mysqli

table: instances

```
instanceID
```

table: objects

```
objectID
instanceID
```

how do i grab all rows from instances, where the instanceID has 0 rows in objects.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not terribly efficient, but you can simply using an inner query like so:

```
select * from instance where instanceID not in (select instanceID from Objects)
```

OR use join which should be faster than inner queries

```
SELECT I.*
FROM instance I LEFT JOIN Objects O ON I.instanceID = O.instanceID
WHERE O.instanceID IS NULL
```

Comment: I wonder whether a `where not exists (correlated subquery)` query could be faster in this case. @user1512064: can there be exactly zero or one records in `objects` with a given instanceID or can there be n>1 records for a given instanceID?

Comment: @VolkerK: you can left join, I was just lazy to think it through :)

Comment: I think the second solution using a LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is way better. That's the way it had to be done without subqueries/exists ...and I still like that syntax more (I'm too old for that `exists` shi....;-) )

Comment: typo aside, the second statement works perfectly. thank you very much =)

Answer (score -1):

`select * from instances where (select count(instanceID) from objects) = 0;`

Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: when tested, returns 0 rows when expecting 1. thank you anyway.